# Array dot Product

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, product

I have a column vector of:

```
a = [[1] [2] [3]]
```

First, how can I get rid of the outer bracket? I need to create the dot product `aT*a` and the answer is supposed to be singular. My current code generates `[[14]]`  but I need `14` by itself.

Here is my current code:

```
SSE = np.inner(np.transpose(a), np.transpose(a))
```

Comment: Why get rid of the outer bracket? That's how a 'column' vector is displayed.  `a` is (3,1) shape, right?  `a.T` is then (1,3).  `dot` on the 3 dimension leaves you with a (1,1) result.

Answer (score 0):

Using `hstack`

```
np.hstack(a).dot(a)
array([14])
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's be picky about notation.

```
a = [[1] [2] [3]]
```

is not valid Python.  You'll get syntax error, even if your goal is a numpy array.

```
In [202]: a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])                                        
In [203]: a.shape                                                            
Out[203]: (3, 1)
In [204]: a                                                                  
Out[204]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [205]: print(a)                                                           
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]]
```

The print/str display of an array omits the commas, but the brackets are an integral part of the display.  They help show the dimensions of the array.  The list equivalent of this array displays as `[[1], [2], [3]]`.

If I do a `dot` of a (1,3) with a (3,1), the result is (1,1).  The `dot` (and your `inner` version, preserves the outer dimensions of the arrays.

```
In [206]: np.dot(a.T,a)                                                      
Out[206]: array([[14]])
In [207]: _.shape                                                            
Out[207]: (1, 1)
```

We can 'flatten' the array, so its shape is now (3,):

```
In [209]: a1 = a.ravel()                                                     
In [210]: a1                                                                 
Out[210]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [211]: np.dot(a1,a1)                                                      
Out[211]: 14
```

`np.dot` has special documented handling for 1d array arguments.  Note that the `.T` transpose is not needed.  Transpose does nothing to the shape a 1d array.

`np.inner` also works, but `np.dot` is used more often:

```
In [215]: np.inner(a.T, a.T)                                                 
Out[215]: array([[14]])
In [216]: np.inner(a1, a1)                                                   
Out[216]: 14
```

And in recent years there's `matmul` function and `@` operator that works similarly:

```
In [217]: a.T@a                                                              
Out[217]: array([[14]])
```

You can remove dimensions after the calculation:

```
In [218]: (a.T@a).squeeze()                                                  
Out[218]: array(14)
In [219]: (a.T@a).item()                                                     
Out[219]: 14
```